# File Upload in Laravel - Display Error to user if they are trying to upload big file

Tags: laravel, file, upload

Within Laravel, I am successfully able to have a user upload a file on a page, but I want to know if there is a way for there to be an error displayed to that user before they submit the page that the file is too big. Something like "The file you selected to upload is 25MB. Get it below 20MB."

Is there some kind of package that can handle this?

Comment: Take a look at Laravel's built in validation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation. They have validation for files where you can check the type and size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validating the file size on client side. (Mentioning this because you have mentioned that you would like to alert the error before form submit.) 
Check the example code below which uses jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input[type="file"]').change(function(event) {
        var fileSize = this.files[0].size;
        var maxAllowedSize = //add your value here;
        // check the file size if its greater than your requirement
        if(size > maxAllowedSize){
          alert('Please upload a smaller file');
          this.val('');
        }

    });
});
```

Validation on server side(you can change mime types as per the file type you want to allow) :

```
<?php 

public function store(Request $request){

    $request->validate([
        'file_input_name' => 'file|max:25000|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png',
        // add validations for other fields here
    ]);
}
```

For more check [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation)

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I needed. I needed to change this.val(''); to                     $(this).val(''); just fyi. And if(fileSize... instead of if(size... for anyone else looking at this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a package to do this, you can create either a `Request` class or use a validator:

**1. Create a `Request` class:**

Run the command `php artisan make:request FileRequest`

Then, on the File generated under `App\Http\Requests\FileRequest` do the following:

- Change the `authorize` method to return `true` instead of `false`.
- Under the `rules` method you return your validation rules:

`return [
      "file_input"      =>      "max:20480", //If your input type's file name is "file_input"
            ];`

According to [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-max), `max rule` verifies that the input size from the user will not exceed the specified number in kilobytes for files.

**2. You can also create a validator in your controller method:**

```
use Validator;

public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->only('file_input'), [
            'file_input' => 'max:20480',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()
                        ->route('your.route.name')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
        }

        // other code here
    }
```